# Python crash on Windows with a datetime close to the epoch

Tags: python, windows, datetime, timestamp

Python 3.7 on Windows 10:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(0).timestamp()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(3600 * 3).timestamp()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(360000).timestamp()
360000.0
```

I understand that on Windows, the range for timestamps is limited to 1970 – 2038 due to 32-bit integer size. But it's really strange that it crashes on a timestamp that should still be allowed. FWIW, I am in UTC+2, so if there is some issue with the time zone, I expected the `3600 * 3` (3 hour) timestamp to work. Can I make this work somehow or should I just accept that very low timestamps are not going to work?

Comment: @Dschoni that's strange, the function was added back in 3.3. Does it work for you with a normal (much higher) timestamp?

Comment: Sorry, I was on the wrong python version. With 3.7.3 on Windows 10, the smallest timestamp I can use is `86400` (found by binary separation)

Comment: I checked quickly on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.7.1 `datetime.fromtimestamp(0).timestamp()` gives me `0.0`

Comment: It says in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) that there might be an OSError when `localtime` fails, so maybe your lowest working integer is not identical with mine.

Comment: Yes, this is Windows-specific. On Linux and OS X, there is no problem with negative timestamps, or timestamps outside the 32-bit range (e.g. in the year 1888 or 2102).

Comment: I checked on several python versions and it seems to be the consistent number `86400` that seems to fail. Can you confirm that same number?

Comment: @Dschoni Yup, same here. Perhaps it checks if the (UTC) date is the 1st of January, 1970 *or* less and disallows those?

Comment: Posted to the Python Bugtracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue37527

Answer (score 3):

Ok I did some digging in the source code of the Python. The problem lies within the function `_PyTime_localtime`. This calls the [localtime_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) function takes 2 arguments `time_t t` and `struct tm *tm`. Where `t` is a `time_t` object to convert and `tm` the resulting time structure. When you pass 0 as `time_t`, which is perfectly valid, the resulting structure has the field `tm_hour` set to 1 on my machine. Also there is other code for Non-Windows variants, which calls [localtime_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) in stead.

Now the problem gets moved to the internally used function `utc_to_seconds`, which takes the time structure (split into arguments like so: `int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second`). Now for the year, month and day there is no problem, it gets converted to an ordinal (which is the correct ordinal btw). But then the function has the following last line:

```
return ((ordinal * 24 + hour) * 60 + minute) * 60 + second;
```

Where EPOCH is supposed to return 62135683200 there, but due to this extra hour we get 62135686800.

This all comes together in the internal function `local_to_seconds`

```
long long t, a, b, u1, u2, t1, t2, lt;
t = utc_to_seconds(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
/* Our goal is to solve t = local(u) for u. */
lt = local(t);
if (lt == -1)
    return -1;
a = lt - t;
u1 = t - a;
t1 = local(u1);
```

Where `t = 62135683200` and `lt = 62135686800`. We end up with `u1 = -3600` which results in the invalid parameter.

So to conclude: The problem is when you call `timestamp`. I'm not exactly sure what the solution would be to fix it in the C-code, but it definitely looks like a bug I guess.

Comment: Interesting. Is the `hour` still added with the first valid timestamp (`86400`)? Is it ever removed in the code that follows?

Comment: Nevertheless probably best to open this as a python bug on the issue tracker.

Comment: @AurelBílý I guess after that timestamp localtime_s returns a proper `struct tm` and doesn't end up with a negative `u1`. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

works nicely even on Windows, if you set the tzinfo, i.e. **use** ***aware*** **datetime**:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(0, tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()
0
```

(Windows 10, Python 3.9.12)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to squeeze a UNIX timestamp from a datetime object... the crux of the issue was detailed by Neijwiert, but all you need to do is to assign a time zone.

In my case, I was parsing a string and needed to convert to a unix timestamp:

```
def string_to_unix_time(dt_string):
    # get the time zone (EST = UTC−05:00)
    tz = timezone(offset=-timedelta(hours=5))
    # parse out the string...
    date, time = dt_string.strip().split()
    month, day, year = date.split('/')
    hour, minute, second = time.split(':')
    # make datetime object...
    dt = datetime(
        year=int(year),
        month=int(month),
        day=int(day),
        hour=int(hour),
        minute=int(minute),
        second=int(second),
        tzinfo=tz,
    )
    
    return dt.timestamp()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)